# Probabilty of a certain run in a 1000 coin flips

Tags: probability, statistics

So a run of $x$ heads has the probability $0.5^x$. 
Thefore a run of $9$ would be $0.5^9 = 0.001953125$.

But what is the chance of that run of $9$ occuring in $1000$ coinflips?
Can anyone please explain how to work this out?

Comment: Know the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution?

Comment: Do you need consecutive 9 heads in 1000 flips OR just 9 heads in any place in 1000 flips?

Comment: Binomial distribution won't get you there. He wants 9 flips in a row to be heads when flipping a coin 1000. Not the same as getting exactly 9 heads in 1000 flips which the binomial distribution would give you the answer to.

Comment: Exactly as Laars says. The chances of a 9 head run happening at least once.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://wangling.me/2008/09/the-probability-of-runs-of-k-consecutive-heads-in-n-coin-tosses.html

Comment: You can get an estimate by considering nine consecutive starting at an index divisible by 9. If this value is low enough, multiplying it by 9 should provide a good estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is an answer based upon  *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function)*. We start with a generating function for words of a two character alphabet $V=\{T,H\}$ which counts words with no consecutive equal characters at all.

These words are called Smirnov or Carlitz words. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information. (You might also find *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125976/generating-functions-combinatorics-problem-of-mirko-couting-vehicles-through-t/2126582#2126582)* helpful.)

> The generating function $A(z)$ counting Smirnov words over a two character alphabet is according to the reference 
>   \begin{align*}
>   A(z)=\left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
>   \end{align*}
>
> The coefficient of $z^n$ of $A(z)$ gives the number of Smirnov words of length $n$, i.e. the number of words with no consecutive equal heads and tails.

Since there is no restriction to the distribution of tails, we can replace each character "T" in a Smirnov word by one or more "T"s, which means to replace
\begin{align*}
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+z^3+\cdots=\color{blue}{\frac{z}{1-z}}
\end{align*}
in the corresponding generating function $A(z)$.

> Based upon $A(z)$ we obtain this way a generating function $B(z)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> B(z)&=\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}-\frac{\color{blue}{\frac{z}{1-z}}}{1+\color{blue}{\frac{z}{1-z}}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &=\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}-z\right)^{-1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> The coefficient of $z^n$ of $B(z)$ gives the number of words of length $n$ with no consecutive equal heads.

We next allow a distribution of heads with runs up to length $8$. This implies a replacement of each character "H" by one up to eight "H"s, which means
\begin{align*}
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+z^3+\cdots+z^8=\frac{z(1-z^8)}{1-z}
\end{align*}

> Based upon $B(z)$ we obtain this way a generating function $C(z)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> C(z)&=\left(1-\frac{\color{blue}{\frac{z(1-z^8)}{1-z}}}{1+\color{blue}{\frac{z(1-z^8)}{1-z}}}-z\right)^{-1}\\
> &=\frac{(1+z+z^2)(1+z^3+z^6)}{1-z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6+z^7+z^8+z^9}
> \end{align*}
>
> The coefficient of $z^n$ of $C(z)$ gives the number of words of length $n$ having no runs of heads of length $9$.

Finally in order to get the number of all words of length $n$ which have a run of heads of length $9$, we take all words and subtract those counted by $C(z)$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> D(z)&=\frac{1}{1-2z}-C(z)\\
> &=\frac{z^9}{(1-2z)(1-z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6+z^7+z^8+z^9)}\\
> &=z^9+3z^{10}+\color{blue}{8}z^{11}+20z^{12}+48z^{13}+112z^{14}+\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> whereby the last line was obtained with some help of Wolfram Alpha.

We observe (blue marked coefficient) in (1) there are $8$ words of length $11$ having a run of (at least) $9$ consecutive heads. These are

\begin{array}{ccc}
HHHHHHHHH\color{blue}{TT}&HHHHHHHHH\color{blue}{HT}&HHHHHHHHH\color{blue}{HH}\\
\color{blue}{T}HHHHHHHHH\color{blue}{T}&HHHHHHHHH\color{blue}{TH}\\
\color{blue}{TT}HHHHHHHHH&\color{blue}{T}HHHHHHHHH\color{blue}{H}\\
&\color{blue}{HT}HHHHHHHHH\\
\end{array}

> The probability of runs of heads of length $9$ in sequences of $10,100$ and $1000$ coin flips is according to WA
>   \begin{align*}
> 2^{-10}\cdot[z^{10}]D(z)&=\frac{3}{1024}\doteq 0.00292969\\
> 2^{-100}\cdot[z^{100}]D(z)&\doteq 0.0875589\\
> 2^{-1000}\cdot[z^{1000}]D(z)&\doteq 0.624241\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: This is super interesting, thank you!

Comment: @ElwoodP: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Great answer. Unfortunately it hasn´t  be read as many times as it should be.  Aside from this I have a question: How did you get from this expression $\frac{z^9}{(1-2z)(1-z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6+z^7+z^8+z^9)}$ to the next line? Thanks in advance for your comment / answer.

Comment: @callculus: Thanks for your nice comment. At *[Wolfram.Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com)* I've typed *Series <expr> at $x=0$* in order to get the series expansion. Manually you would probably do long polynomial division to determine the first few coefficients.