# What is the probability of 12 girls being born in a row in a hospital with 27,123 births annually?

Tags: probability

There is some [hype](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/06/world/europe/poland-village-girls-no-boys.html?te=1&nl=morning-briefing&emc=edit_MBE_p_20190807&section=whatElse?campaign_id=51&instance_id=11461&segment_id=15935&user_id=fba15fa30391e42b21002ece80749d99&regi_id=60950956ion=whatElse) now about a Polish village where the last 12 children born were all girls.

The probability that the last 12 newborns in a village are all girls is around 0.03%, so around 3000 villages give us a solid 50% chance of this happening, so I would say this is no big deal.

However I was thinking how often this happens in large hospitals and goes unnoticed.

According to some [stats I found](https://www.statista.com/statistics/590463/leading-us-hospitals-annual-births/) the Northside Hospital in Atlanta has seen 27,123 births in 2016.

So what is the probability that at least 12 girls in a row were born there in 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, using stuff like Markov chains and generating functions (for example, in the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145628/probabilty-of-a-certain-run-in-a-1000-coin-flips) question).

Helpfully, the author Greg Egan has [a post](http://www.gregegan.net/QUARANTINE/Runs/Runs.html) on the topic on his website, where he includes a calculator. If we put in 2 as the number of outcomes (girl/boy, assuming equal probability of each), with 27,123 trials and looking for a run of 12, we get:

> Probability of a run of at least 12 heads in 27,123 coin tosses is 96.365698%
>
> The average number of coin tosses needed to achieve a run of 12 heads is 8,190

So if you listed all the births at the Northside Hospital for a single year in order, you would actually be very surprised if you *didn't* see a run of at least 12 girls in there somewhere. On the other hand, a run of 18 has a probability of only about 5%, so if you saw 20 or more girls in a row in the records you would have a bit more reason to be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation in Maple (runtime $12$ seconds) :

[image]